# setImageBitmap() lags UI

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

When I call `setImageBitmap()` on any **imageView**, it lags the UI. And I am using a **listView** so I have to set a imageView while scrolling. Please don't suggest using Picasso or other image download helpers because the problem isn't related to downloading the problem and it doesn't helped to use that kind of libraries.

Edit:
Adapter:

```
public class GönderiItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final Vector<String> mVeri;
    private boolean mProfil = false;
    private boolean mKullanıcı;
    private boolean mArama = false;
    private Profil mProfilBilgi;
    private String mAramaString;



public GönderiItemAdapter( Activity pActivity, String[] pVeri, boolean pKullanıcı, Profil pProfililgi ){

    this(pActivity, pVeri);

    mProfil      = true;
    mKullanıcı   = pKullanıcı;
    mProfilBilgi = pProfililgi;

}

public GönderiItemAdapter( Activity pActivity, final String[] pVeri, String pAramaString ){

    this(pActivity, pVeri);

    mAramaString = pAramaString;
    mArama = true;
}

public GönderiItemAdapter( Activity pActivity, final String[] pVeri){

    if( Ayarlar.sGönderiler == null )
        Ayarlar.yükleGönderiler( pActivity );

    mActivity   = pActivity;

    mVeri = new Vector<String>();

    for( int i = 0; i < pVeri.length; ++i )
        mVeri.add( pVeri[ i ] );

    mProfil     = false;

}

public void ekleÜst( String[] pVeri ){

    for( int i = pVeri.length - 1; i >= 0; --i ){

        Gönderi gönderi = Ayarlar.alGönderi( pVeri[ i ], mActivity, false);

        if( !gönderi.mGönderenId.equals( "-1" ) )
            mVeri.add( 0 , pVeri[ i ] );

    }       
}

public void ekleAlt( String[] pVeri, final TextView pMetin ){

    for( int i = 0; i < pVeri.length; ++i ){

        Gönderi gönderi = Ayarlar.alGönderi( pVeri[ i ], mActivity, false);             

        if( gönderi.mGönderenId.equals( "-1" ) )
            mActivity.runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pMetin.setText( R.string.dahayok );
                }
            } );

        else
            mVeri.add( pVeri[ i ] );
    }

}

public void al( ){
    GenelEşzamansızİşlem giş = new GenelEşzamansızİşlem();
    giş.arkaplanİşlem = new Thread( new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            for( int i = 0; i < mVeri.size(); ++i )
                Ayarlar.alGönderi( mVeri.get( i ), mActivity, false);

        }
    } );
    if( Araçlar.mobilVeri(mActivity) )
        giş.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);

    else
        giş.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}

static public void al2( final String[] pVeri, final Activity pActivity ){
    GenelEşzamansızİşlem giş = new GenelEşzamansızİşlem();
    giş.arkaplanİşlem = new Thread( new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {     
            if( Ayarlar.sGönderiler == null )
                Ayarlar.yükleGönderiler(pActivity);

            Vector<String> idVector = new Vector<String>();

            for( int i = 0; i < pVeri.length; ++i )
                if( !Ayarlar.sGönderiler.containsKey( pVeri[i] ) )
                    idVector.add( pVeri[i] );

            String[] idArray = new String[ idVector.size() ];

            for( int i = 0; i < idArray.length; ++i )
                idArray[ i ] = idVector.get( i );

            if( idArray.length > 0 )
                Ayarlar.alTopluGönderi(idArray, pActivity);

        }
    } );

    try{
        giş.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR).get();
    }catch( Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public void güncelle( ){

    for( int i = 0; i < mVeri.size(); ++i ){
        Ayarlar.alGönderi( mVeri.get( i ), mActivity, false).güncelle( mActivity );
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount(){

    if( mProfil )
        return mVeri.size() + 1;

    return mVeri.size();
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount(){
    return 2;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position){

    if( mProfil && position == 0 )
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled(){
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled( int position ){
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if( mProfil && position == 0 )
    {

        View v = inflater.inflate( R.layout.header_profil, null);


        final Button sağ        = (Button) v.findViewById( R.id.sag  );
        View   line1            =          v.findViewById( R.id.line1);
        final Button orta       = (Button) v.findViewById( R.id.orta );
        View   line2            =          v.findViewById( R.id.line2);
        final Button sol        = (Button) v.findViewById( R.id.sol  );

        if( mKullanıcı ){

            sağ.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );

            sağ.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ( ( ExplorerActivity )mActivity ).yeniGönderi();
                }
            } );

            sağ.setText( R.string.yeniGonderi );

        } 

        else{

            sağ.setVisibility( View.GONE );
            line2.setVisibility( View.GONE );

            if( !Ayarlar.sFavoriler.contains( mProfilBilgi.mID ) )
                sol.setText( R.string.favoriEkle );
            else
                sol.setText( R.string.favoriCikar );

            sol.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );

            sol.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ( ( ExplorerActivity )mActivity ).favori( mProfilBilgi.mID );

                    if( !Ayarlar.sFavoriler.contains( mProfilBilgi.mID ) )
                        sol.setText( R.string.favoriEkle );
                    else
                        sol.setText( R.string.favoriCikar );
                }
            } );

        }

        v.findViewById( R.id.profil ).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ( ( ExplorerActivity )mActivity ).gösterProfil( mProfilBilgi );
            }
        } );

        return v;   
    }   

    else{

        if( mProfil )
            position -= 1;

        View v;
        Gönderi g;

        if( convertView == null ){

            v = inflater.inflate( R.layout.gonderi_liste_nesnesi, null);

            g = new Gönderi();
            g.mAnaDüzen         = (LinearLayout) v;
            g.mProfilFotoğrafı  = (CircularImageView) v.findViewById( R.id.profil_photo );
            g.mGönderenAdı      = (TextView) v.findViewById( R.id.gonderen_adi );
            g.mGönderiZamanı    = (TextView) v.findViewById( R.id.gonderi_tarihi );
            g.mDönem            = (TextView) v.findViewById( R.id.gonderen_donemi );
            g.mGönderi          = (TextView) v.findViewById( R.id.gonderi );
            g.mBeğen            = (TextView) v.findViewById( R.id.begen );
            g.mBeğeniText       = (TextView) v.findViewById( R.id.begeniSayi );

            v.setTag( g );

        }
        else{
            g = (Gönderi) convertView.getTag();
            v = convertView;
        }

        final Gönderi gönderi = Ayarlar.alGönderi( mVeri.get( position ), mActivity, false);

        g.mGönderenAdıString = gönderi.mGönderenAdıString;
        g.mDüzenliTarih = gönderi.mDüzenliTarih;
        g.mDönemString = gönderi.mDönemString;
        g.mGönderiHamMetin = gönderi.mGönderiHamMetin;
        g.mBeğeniTextString = gönderi.mBeğeniTextString;

        g.mBeğeni       = gönderi.mBeğeni;
        g.mBeğenildi    = gönderi.mBeğenildi;
        g.mBeğeniVerisi = gönderi.mBeğeniVerisi;
        g.mGönderenId   = gönderi.mGönderenId;
        g.mBeğeniSayısı = gönderi.mBeğeniSayısı;
        g.mGönderiId    = gönderi.mGönderiId;

        g.ayarla( mArama, mAramaString, mActivity);


        if( !mArama ){

            g.beğeniİşlemler( mActivity );

            if( g.mBeğenildi ){
                g.mBeğen.setOnClickListener( g.mBeğenmeİşlem );

                g.mBeğen.setText( R.string.hoslanma );
            }

            else
                g.mBeğen.setOnClickListener( g.mBeğenİşlem );

            final Gönderi foo = g;

            g.mBeğeniText.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog( mActivity );

                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_begeni);

                    ListView liste = (ListView) dialog.findViewById( R.id.liste );

                    Vector<Profil> profiller = new Vector<Profil>();

                    for( int i = 0; i < foo.mBeğeni.size(); ++i ){

                        Profil p = Ayarlar.alProfil( foo.mBeğeni.get( i ).mGönderenID , mActivity);

                        Log.w( "id" , p.mID);

                        if( p != null && !p.mID.equals( Ayarlar.sMevcutId ) )
                            profiller.add( p );

                    }

                    KartAdapter adapter = new KartAdapter(mActivity, profiller, mActivity, dialog);

                    liste.setAdapter( adapter );

                    if( profiller.size() != 0 )
                        dialog.show();
                }
            } );


            g.mProfilFotoğrafı.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    ((ExplorerActivity) mActivity).açProfil( gönderi.mGönderenId );
                }
            });

            g.mGönderenAdı.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    ((ExplorerActivity) mActivity).açProfil( gönderi.mGönderenId );
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            g.mAnaDüzen.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    ((ExplorerActivity) mActivity).açGönderi( gönderi.mGönderiId );
                }
            });
        }

        return v;
    }   
}

}
```

Comment: That's very likely the garbage collector kicking in because the images take up memory that it wants to recycle. There's no answer to your question if you don't give any information about the nature of the bitmaps (size, origin, different for each list item or not...).

Comment: They are loaded from server and in different sizes and different for each item, but it doesn't matter if I setdrawable from resources

Comment: Since you're using ListView I assume that you have some kind of thumbnails located in it. And perhaps you're loading a big bitmap (not in sample size) in order to place it there. But without the code which is used to do this I cannot give any recommendations. Can you please post a code how you get a Bitmap and how you pass it to ImageView? And also it will be helpful if you post your ListView Adapter.

Comment: If you really want I can post the adapter but it is really complicated and works together with another classes, and I am loading bitmaps using Picasso. When I saw it lags that way I tried load image into bitmap using Picasso then set bitmap to imageview. But it lags whenever I call ImageView.setImageBitmap() or setImageDrawable

Comment: Use Traceview to determine where your problem really lies.

Comment: Wait a bit I will give it a shot

Comment: Using Traceview is a good idea but if my theory is correct you won't find anything since the garbage collector won't show in Traceview. To confirm my theory do a "adb -d logcat dalvikvm:D *:S" (if you use dalvik) and you might see that the ui lags whenever the gc kicks in. It's not easy to spot but that's how I found (and finally fixed) the lags in one of my ListViews.

Comment: There are too many invalidate calls on my layout it may be because I am using a little complicated layout, and yes there are tons of gc_for_alloc freed bla bla messages in log :D

Comment: You should be able to see the gc calls as soon as you start scrolling. If that's the case you need to find a way to prevent the gc from being called too often. This is a complex task and I'm not sure it has a simple SO answer.

Comment: It calls gc too many times even if I don't use setImageBitmap, btw what should I do to achieve that? At least you can tell what causes gc calls as an answer

Comment: If the gc kicks in without the setImageBitmap then you have more issues than just the images and using Traceview might be the way to go first. The gc kicks in if Android wants to free some memory which happens more frequently if the app allocates a lot of memory e.g. by adding many and or large images to a ListView but of course there could be a gazillion different reasons. Anyway you also need to look into the memory use of your app which I would do using MAT (http://www.eclipse.org/mat/).

Comment: using non-english identifiers in the code scares away many developers, do you know this?

Comment: Yes I know, but I had to use that characters. I will pass that project to other developers who doesn't know English, so it must be as understandable as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with reducing gc calls and organizing my adapter. But the real problem was with file output. I have reduced calls to file output functions and it solved my problems. I put all of the file outputting in onPause method. It lags a little when app pauses but it is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ViewHolder Design Pattern`:

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder

with Image place holder to prevent your list images to mess up and after your download completed replace the image place holder with your image if it is being displayed or

you can use the new android widget:

https://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html#recyclerview

Comment: I am using a kind of view holder design pattern but I still have the problem

Comment: can you post your adapter!